# casper.js: press key "enter" in an ExtJs input field

Tags: javascript, forms, keypress, casperjs, extjs2

I have an ExtJs text field on a page. I am filling it with some value in casper.js, which works fine.
Then I want to focus this field and press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, as there is no `<form>` around it to submit.

What I tried was:

```
casper.then(function() {
  // the text field is filled with the string
  this.sendKeys('#searchfield', 'some text');

  this.evaluate(function() {
    // this does not put the field in focus        
    document.querySelector('#searchfield').focus();

    // so 'pressing' enter has no effect at all
    var evt = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');
    evt.initKeyboardEvent('keypress', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13);
    document.dispatchEvent(evt);
  });
});
```

Do you have any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

your code

```
evt.initKeyboardEvent('keypress', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13);
```

Look at the fourth param, I guess it should be the trigger element. Here should be `document.querySelector('#searchfield')` .

One hint: In casper evaluate, return a true in final, and then you will get null if there is any error in evaluate.

```
var result = this.evaluate(function(){ /*code is here*/ return true;})
```

check the result, if success

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The fourth parameter is the `viewArg` and usually just the `window` object. Changing it to my element doesn't change anything unfortunately. It just doesn't get pressed.

Comment: I now just use `\n` to send enter key, try this `this.sendKeys('#searchfield', 'some text\n');`

Answer (score 0):

2 suggestions:

The first: try `this.thenEvaluate` instead of `evaluate`. then is needed to make sure the async sequance works correctly.

The second: this maybe a client js issue. In a browser you could just check the js console, But not here. so you should add a little debugging helper.

```
casper.on('log.message', function(msg){
  console.log(msg);
}
```

Which would transfer your remote console message to you console. now you can debug the remote context with `console.log()` and see where (and if) It breaks.

you should also set `verbose=true` and `logLevel="debug"` for this to work.

good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry for my delay. I figured that the problem is not on casper level, but that it doesn't even in normal browser window (Chrome).